# Are the TIE Fighter pilots clones?

Tags: star-wars

(inspired by [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/149334/where-did-the-idea-that-tie-fighters-are-weak-and-disposable-come-from))

In the movies the pilots of TIE Fighters are shown wearing the same (or at least similar) masks like the Stormtroopers.

Are they clones too? The Stormtrooper clones are "programmed" for grunts but programming a clone for a pilot would be much more difficult.

Comment: [Stormtroopers are not, in general, clones](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/41198/31051)

Comment: No. They aren't

Comment: Yeah, arguably a duplicate of this: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/41198/51379

Comment: Clones were used as pilots as well as "grunts" during the Clone Wars (see, e.g., the beginning of Episode III). Since the clones were phased out as "grunts" they'd be phased out as TIE fighter pilots, too.